# Querying by multiple associations (OR) in CakePHP 3.0

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to build a (more or less complex) query with CakePHP 3.0 beta 3. I have the following entities:

User belongsToMany Group
Task belongsToMany User (aliased 'Recipients')
Task belongsToMany Group

It is a tasks management system. A task can be issued either to specific users, or to named groups of users.

I am now trying to find tasks that belong to the current user OR to a group that the current user is a member of (all tasks relevant to a specific user). I have got the user id and a list of groups that the user is a member of.

I have managed to get it to work using the following code:

```
$queryOptions = [
    'contain' => [
        'Recipients', 'Groups'
    ]
];

$tasksForUser = $this->Tasks->find('all', $queryOptions)->matching('Recipients', function ($q) use ($user_id) {
    return $q->where(['Recipients.id' => $user_id]);
})->toArray();

$tasksForGroup = $this->Tasks->find('all', $queryOptions)->matching('Groups', function($q) use ($group_ids) {
    return $q->where(['Groups.id IN' => $group_ids]);
})->toArray();

$this->set('tasks', array_merge($tasksForUser, $tasksForGroup));
```

CakePHP 3.0 claims to have a sophicsticated ORM model, so is there a way to execute this in a single query? It might give me the ability to filter out duplicates on the fly.

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `UNION` of two queries. This statement is supported by the ORM. MySQL implements it by by default clearing out duplicate results (assumes `DISTINCT`) so you're good to go.

Cake's documentation has [a nice example](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#unions) which should apply to your case like this:

```
$tasksForUser = $tasks->find()
    ->contain('Recipients', function ($q) use ($user_id) {
        return $q->where(['Recipients.id' => $user_id]);
    })
;

$tasksForGroup = $tasks->find()
    ->contain('Groups', function($q) use ($group_ids) {
        return $q->where(['Groups.id IN' => $group_ids]);
    })
;

$tasksForGroup->union($tasksForUser);
```

So all you need is to place the code in your model to be called from your controller as a custom find.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful. First, it complained about the two queries having a different amount of columns, but I was able to solve this by using select().
Then I ran into a strange issue: I was not able to make contain() to include both the Recipients and the Groups associations in the final result. With $tasksForGroup->union($tasksForUser) it only included the users. Switching it to $tasksForUser->union($tasksForGroup), it only included the groups. I have worked around this by using union() to just get me a list of tasks ids and issue a second query for the full result set.

Comment: Unions [require "compatible" results](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) (having the same fields with the same type). Perhaps that can explain why it drops your fields. A good strategy is indeed to just get the ids and work with those.